# Referring to tikz picture again in the same document

Tags: tikz-pgf

*I couldn't really think of a reasonable title for this question; but anyhow, here goes:*

I saw a very interesting question and solution today [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101047/drawing-tree-canopy-in-latex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}
\tikzset{
  treetop/.style = {
    decoration={random steps, segment length=0.4mm},
    decorate
  },
  trunk/.style = {
    decoration={random steps, segment length=2mm, amplitude=0.2mm},
    decorate
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {
  \fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] (0,0) ++(-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,-3);
}
\foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {
   \fill [green!\f!black, treetop] ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From this solution I would like to know if it was possible to copy this diagram `n` times by simply referring to the code shown. For example, if I was drawing a field, drawn as a simple horizontal line:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0) -- (10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Could I then repeat the tree drawn, say `4` times along this line to represent a portion of a forest, scaled accordingly? For example:

[image]

Obviously these can be created by a simple for loop, however, I guess I'm just trying to find a way of re-applying the code for the tree numerous times.

Comment: You can save the picture in a savebox and reuse the content of the saved box later on. Personally, I'd be against that idea because generating randomly shaped trees is much nicer!

Comment: could you provide an example :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Marc van Dongen commented you could save the picure in a `\savebox` and reuse that. But, then all the pictures will be identical.  Instead, you can define a command for the `tikzpicture` and reuse it which yields a different tree for each instance, or define a macro to be useable within a `\tikzpicture` environment.

### 1. Reuse entire `tikzpicture`:

[image]

### Notes:

- If you wish to reuse the same `\Tree` code *within* a `tikzpicture` then  define a macro that only contains the two `foreach` loops, and either use a `scope to shift each instance to the right, or provide a parameter which controls where the drawing is done.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}
\tikzset{
  treetop/.style = {
    decoration={random steps, segment length=0.4mm},
    decorate
  },
  trunk/.style = {
    decoration={random steps, segment length=2mm, amplitude=0.2mm},
    decorate
  }
}

\newcommand*{\Tree}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {
  \fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] (0,0) ++(-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,-3);
}
\foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {
   \fill [green!\f!black, treetop] ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
}
\end{tikzpicture}}%

\begin{document}
\Tree \Tree \Tree \Tree
\end{document}
```

---

### 2. Using `scope`:

If you wish to reuse the same `\Tree` code *within* a `tikzpicture` you could  define a macro that only contains the two `foreach` loops, and  use a `scope to shift each instance to the right

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}
\tikzset{
  treetop/.style = {
    decoration={random steps, segment length=0.4mm},
    decorate
  },
  trunk/.style = {
    decoration={random steps, segment length=2mm, amplitude=0.2mm},
    decorate
  }
}

\newcommand*{\Tree}{%
    \foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {
      \fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] (0,0) ++(-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,-3);
    }
    \foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {
       \fill [green!\f!black, treetop] ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
    }
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree 

\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
    \Tree 
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \Tree 
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
    \Tree
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### 3. Parametrized Version:

Another way of reusing the same code within a `tikzpicture` would be to define a macro which contains the two `foreach` loops, and takes a parameter which controls where the drawing is done.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}
\tikzset{
  treetop/.style = {
    decoration={random steps, segment length=0.4mm},
    decorate
  },
  trunk/.style = {
    decoration={random steps, segment length=2mm, amplitude=0.2mm},
    decorate
  }
}

\newcommand*{\Tree}[2]{%
    % #1 = origin coordinate
    \begin{scope}[xshift=#1 cm, yshift=#2 cm]
        \foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {
          \fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] (0,0) ++(-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,-3);
        }
        \foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {
           \fill [green!\f!black, treetop] ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
        }
    \end{scope}
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree{0}{0}
    \Tree{2}{0}
    \Tree{4}{0} 
    \Tree{6}{0}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### 4. Fancy Version

If you are parametrizing the macro, might as well add optional parameters to be able to control the draw options for the treetop and trunk as well:

[image]

### Notes:

- My color choices were based on Pandora, but I have been told that on Earth, well at least in the UK :-), trees in nature do not exhibit these kind of colors. Perhaps someone who can chose more aesthetically pleasing colors can edit the choices here.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}
\tikzset{
  treetop/.style = {
    decoration={random steps, segment length=0.4mm},
    decorate
  },
  trunk/.style = {
    decoration={random steps, segment length=2mm, amplitude=0.2mm},
    decorate
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Tree}{%
    O{green!\f!black}% #1 = tree top options
    O{brown!\f!black}% #2 = trunk options
    m% #3 = xshift
    m% #4 = yshift
    }{%
    \begin{scope}[xshift=#3 cm, yshift=#4 cm]
        \foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {
          \fill [#2, trunk] (0,0) ++(-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,-3);
        }
        \foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {
           \fill [#1, treetop] ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
        }
    \end{scope}
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree{0}{0}
    \Tree[orange!\f!black][gray!\f!blue]{2}{0}
    \Tree[olive!\f!cyan][orange!\f!violet]{4}{0} 
    \Tree[orange!\f!red][brown!\f!black]{6}{0}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is brilliant! I prefer the first version, though ;).

Comment: @cfr: :-) You obviously don't live in a place where you have such colorful trees!!

Comment: Or I am just very boring. The pic version looks nice, too.

Answer (score 7):

All previous answers were (and still are) valid with `TiKZ` versions previous to v3.0. But [`TikZ 3.0`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153392/what-are-the-new-features-in-tikz-pgf-3-0) introduced a new tool called `pics` (more information in pgfmanual's section 18. *Pics: Small Pictures on Paths*) which can be used to declare and reuse complex figures without having to use new `shapes`.

With this tool, any group of commands can be declared inside a `pic`

```
   my tree/.pic={
     \foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {
       \fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] (-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,3);
     }
     \foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {
       \fill [green!\f!black, treetop](0,3) ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
     }
   }
```

and used afterwards with drawing commands like `\pic at (x,y) {my tree};` or `\path (x,y) pic {my tree};`.

If pics are declared with arguments, another declaration syntax is needed:

```
   pics/second tree/.style 2 args={
    code={
         \foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {
             \fill [#2, trunk] (-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,3);
          }
          \foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {
             \fill [#1, treetop](0,3) ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
          }
       }
   }
```

An example using both syntax could be:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shapes,shapes.geometric,patterns}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{treetop/.style = {decoration={random steps, segment length=0.4mm},decorate},trunk/.style = {decoration={random steps, segment length=2mm, amplitude=0.2mm},decorate}}

\tikzset{
   my tree/.pic={
     \foreach \w/\f in {0.3/30,0.2/50,0.1/70} {
       \fill [brown!\f!black, trunk] (-\w/2,0) rectangle +(\w,3);
     }
     \foreach \n/\f in {1.4/40,1.2/50,1/60,0.8/70,0.6/80,0.4/90} {
       \fill [green!\f!black, treetop](0,3) ellipse (\n/1.5 and \n);
     }
   }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (2,0) {my tree};
\draw (4,0) pic {my tree};
\path (6,0) pic {second tree={red!\f}{purple!\f}};
\pic at (0,0) {second tree={orange!\f!black}{gray!\f!blue}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]